# Using Regular Expression to Format Date

Tags: javascript

I am trying to ensure the date is in YYYY-MM-DD with the following code:

```
var exp = \d{4}-(?:0[1-9]|1[0-2])-(?:0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01]);

for(i=0; i<array.length; i++)
    if(!exp.test(array[i].value)
        //do something
```

What i have is currently not working, the contents of my if statement are not executing, which leads me to believe either my if statement is set up wrong or my regular expression is wrong, I am stuck on it and cannot figure it out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as you mentioned you want date format `yyyy-mm-dd` you can use bellow `regex`

```
/([12]\d{3}-(0[1-9]|1[0-2])-(0[1-9]|[12]\d|3[01]))/
```

```js
var exp = /([12]\d{3}-(0[1-9]|1[0-2])-(0[1-9]|[12]\d|3[01]))/;
let yourDate= "2018-09-26";

if(exp.test(yourDate)) {
   console.log('Date Formated!');
}
```

Comment: wrong result for `"2019-02-29"` (should be invalid)

Comment: @KamilKiełczewski exactly - see [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59094412/295783)

Answer (score 1):

Your regex will allow invalid dates. Here is how to test

```js
const isDate = dString => {
  const [yyyy, mm, dd] = dString.split("-");
  let d = new Date(yyyy, mm - 1, dd, 15, 0, 0, 0); // handling DST
  return d.getFullYear() === +yyyy &&   // casting to number
         d.getMonth()    === mm - 1 &&
         d.getDate()     === +dd;
}
const arr = ["2019-01-01", "2019-02-29"]

arr.forEach(dString => console.log(isDate(dString)))
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't check your regexp, but you should put it between `/` and `/` - however for date validation regexp are not good tool - e.g. case `2019-02-29` is invalid... But you can use it for initial format checking e.g.

```js
let dateString = "2019-05-14";

let [d,year,month,day]= dateString.match(/(\d{4})-(\d{2})-(\d{2})/)||[]

if(d) {
  // here make deeper validation
  console.log({year,month,day})
} else {
  console.log('invalid');
}
```

Comment: Yours allow 9999-99-99 :)

Comment: yes, as I explain in answer - you can use regexp only for initial validation (I don't perform deeper validation in this answer)

Answer (score 0):

You are not declaring your regex correctly. you need to use `/regex/`.
Also, you are testing if your string doesn't match, you might want to make sure that's what you really want.

```js
var exp = /\d{4}-(?:0[1-9]|1[0-2])-(?:0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])/;
let dateString = "2019-05-40";

if(!exp.test(dateString)) {
   console.log('not matching');
}
```

Comment: I am trying to find the dates that dont match so yes, i need the !

Comment: alright, then your only problem was the way you were defining your regex.

Comment: One more problem: Try "2019-02-29"